# Why does one convert Java objects to JSON and vice versa?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am exploring the Jackson library and its related topics. I am unable to understand why is it necessary to convert Java objects to JSON and vice versa? This is really a show-stopper for me.

Comment: You can try JacksonUtils API for reference.

Comment: Are you basically asking "why would I want to serialize objects to JSON" (so you can send them to something that understands JSON) and "why would I want to deserialize JSON to objects" (so you can consume something that talks to you in JSON)? I mean, it's kind of self-explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure you know what Jackson is for? Its **purpose** is to take Java objects and serialize them in a storable format (amongst *a lot* of other formats, JSON).

Comment: JSON is a way of representing objects as strings. Are you asking why it is useful to be able to convert things to and from strings?

Comment: If you're wanting someone else to be able to use your data it's helpful to put it in a common format. JSON, XML, Soap, etc... are such formats.

Comment: Also, this is a strong case of the "XY Problem": You have problem X, and you think you can solve X by doing Y, but Y has problems, so you ask about Y, but don't mention X. Experienced people tell you "Well, that's a strange question, but Y is like this and that", but that doesn't actually solve your original problem, because Y is a dead end. If you added X to your question, you'd have helpful answers immediately.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is considered to be a convenient "Transfer Encoding". It's more compact than XML, and is simple for humans to both read and generate by hand.

Most languages have a fairly mature JSON encoder/decoder, so it's possible for your Java application to generate a JSON message that Javascript running in a browser can read. If there *is* an error somewhere in the process, it's easy for you to read the JSON text and understand whether the mistake is in your Java or Javascript code.

There's not much point of encoding things as JSON if you're not transferring data between two different systems - you probably wouldn't want to translate a Java object into JSON, pass it into a different method, and then translate it back into a Java Object. You'd be losing type safety, and doing a lot of work for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization to JSON lets you access the data contained in the objects from software not written in Java such as Javascript code running in a web client etc.

Java native (binary) serialization is very difficult to read from anything else than Java and it's not straightforward to keep backwards compatibility when your classes change.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is commonly used for [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

It's useful to convert a Java object to JSON any time you can't easily pass the Java object itself to where you need it, for example storing it, or making HTTP requests. Vice versa for when you're reading it, to convert it back to a Java object to use.